# Её зовут Ольга или Ольгой?

Tags: согласование, ономастика

Как следует правильно составлять подобные предложения с называнием имени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Ожегова:
[**звать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/67722)
**3.** *кого (что) кем* или *им.*, или (при вопросе) *как.* Именовать, называть.
*Отец зовёт сына Ванюшей (Ванюша). Ребёнок зовёт няню мамой.*
**4. зовут, звали** и (прост.) **звать** *кого кем* или *им.*, или (при вопросе) *как.* Указывает на личное имя кого-нибудь. *Как тебя зовут (звать)? Мальчика зовут Вася (Васей). Этого человека звали Иван Иванович (Иваном Ивановичем).*

При глаголе **звать** возможен как именительный, так и творительный падеж.

***Ее зовут Ольга.*** Ольга Колосова. В нашем ресторане она — свой человек (А. Данилова).
*Она знала, что ей четырнадцать лет и **ее зовут Ольгой**...* (А. Платонов)

В словаре управления:
ЗВАТЬ [именовать; называть] сочетается с формами именительного и творительного падежей. *Этого мальчика зовут Петя / Петей; Ему было двадцать пять лет, звали его Иваном Ивановичем* (Гарш.); *Уля не знала фамилии этой девушки, все звали её Люда* (Ф.)